Multiple Wordpress Sites on Nginx on local server
I am trying to setup multiple wordpress sites on a single local server so the domain would be 192.168.1.43. How do I setup the domain for each of the sites for local access under the 192.168.1.43 domain?
Site 1
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/site1/wordpress;

        index index.php;

        server_name 192.168.1.43/site1/wordpress;

        location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock;
        }
}

Site 2
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/site2/wordpress;

        index index.php;

        server_name 192.168.1.43/site2/wordpress;

        location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock;
        }
}


The server name is 192.168.1.43. The /site1/wordpress part belongs in the location statement.
As /site1/wordpress is path of the URL used to request the site, it should not also appear in the root statement.
If you intend to access your sites using the URLs http://192.168.1.43/site1/wordpress/ and http://192.168.1.43/site2/wordpress/ then the following configuration may work:
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www;

    index index.php;

    server_name 192.168.1.43;

    location /site1/wordpress {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /site1/wordpress/index.php?$args;
    }
    location /site2/wordpress {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /site2/wordpress/index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock;
    }
}

